Boolean subtract enlarged
I create mainly moving parts for 3D printing, where there are parts rotating around or moving along each other. For example:

I want to make a cube or cylinder around it with this shape subtracted. Easy, using boolean. But I also need say 0.3mm gap between them. I usually dublicate and enlarge the object to be subtracted, but that's quite clumsy. Is there a better way?

Use Alt+D to linked-duplicate your input geo. This will mean if you edit the original the new one will update with that mesh as well.

Keep this object in the same location as the original, select it then the original and then use Ctrl+P > Set as Parent (Keep Transform). This way it will keep the objects in the same place when you move the original.

Then use a Displace modifier on the duped object that looks like this.

The strength value will control the size of your gap.
Then you just boolean your target object with the Displaced object.

You could also achieve this effect with a Geometry nodes modifier on your target object by putting all of your bolt subtractor objects into one collection, displacing them in GN and subtracting from the target object that way. Then you can skip the whole parenting deal and it will just automatically subtract your objects with the correct spacing.


